# class properties window: Messages button is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I've just migrated from XP to Win7 and installed visual studio Pro 2008 without any problem.

But now I can't add a message handler using the class Properties window, because simply Messages button is missing.

I tried by myself (some settings, reinstall...), searched here and googled but no solution so far.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Switching from XP to win7 shouldn't affect anything. Using VS 2008 in XP shouldn't be any different than using it in Win7.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking on the file in solution explorer, click the file in class View!!